# How do I mutate in a match which borrows an immutable value?

Tags: rust, ownership, borrowing

I can understand borrowing/ownership concepts in Rust, but I have no idea how to work around this case:

```rust
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

struct Val {
    t: HashMap<u16, u16>,
    l: HashSet<u16>,
}

impl Val {
    fn new() -> Val {
        Val {
            t: HashMap::new(),
            l: HashSet::new(),
        }
    }

    fn set(&mut self, k: u16, v: u16) {
        self.t.insert(k, v);
        self.l.insert(v);
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, v: &u16) -> bool {
        self.l.remove(v)
    }

    fn do_work(&mut self, v: u16) -> bool {
        match self.t.get(&v) {
            None => false,
            Some(r) => self.remove(r),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Val::new();

    v.set(123, 100);
    v.set(100, 1234);

    println!("Size before: {}", v.l.len());
    println!("Work: {}", v.do_work(123));
    println!("Size after: {}", v.l.len());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7c1e46e7601599a25950daba670fb6ab)

The compiler has the error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:28:24
   |
26 |         match self.t.get(&v) {
   |               ------ immutable borrow occurs here
27 |             None => false,
28 |             Some(r) => self.remove(r),
   |                        ^^^^^------^^^
   |                        |    |
   |                        |    immutable borrow later used by call
   |                        mutable borrow occurs here
```

I don't understand why I can't mutate in the match arm when I did a `get` (read value) before; the `self.t.get` is finished when the mutation via `remove` begins.

Is this due to scope of the result (`Option<&u16>`) returned by the `get`?  It's true that the lifetime of the result has a scope inside the match expression, but this design-pattern is used very often (mutate in a match expression).

How do I work around the error?

Comment: Please don't include "thank you" in questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Ok, sorry. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration of function `HashMap::<K,V>::get()` is, a bit simplified:

```
pub fn get<'s>(&'s self, k: &K) -> Option<&'s V>
```

This means that it returns an optional reference to the contained value, not the value itself. Since the returned reference points to a value inside the map, it actually borrows the map, that is, you cannot mutate the map while this reference exists. This restriction is there to protect you, what would happen if you remove this value while the reference is still alive?

So when you write:

```
match self.t.get(&v) {
    None => false,
    //r: &u16
    Some(r) => self.remove(r)
}
```

the captured `r` is of type `&u16` and its lifetime is that of `self.t`, that is, it is borrowing it. Thus you cannot get a mutable reference to `self`, that is needed to call remove.

The simplest solution for your problem is the *`clone()` solves every lifetime issue* pattern. Since your values are of type `u16`, that is `Copy`, it is actually trivial:

```
match self.t.get(&v) {
    None => false,
    //r: u16
    Some(&r) => self.remove(&r)
}
```

Now `r` is actually of type `u16` so it borrows nothing and you can mutate `self` at will.

If your key/value types weren't `Copy` you could try and `clone` them, if you are willing to pay for that. If not, there is still another option as your `remove()` function does not modify the `HashMap` but an unrelated `HashSet`. You can still mutate that set if you take care not to reborrow `self`:

```
    fn remove2(v: &u16, l: &mut HashSet<u16>) -> bool {
        l.remove(v)
    }
    fn do_work(&mut self, v: u16) -> bool {
        match self.t.get(&v) {
            None => false,
            //selt.t is borrowed, now we mut-borrow self.l, no problem
            Some(r) => Self::remove2(r, &mut self.l)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove value from `HashMap` by using `value` you get, not `key`.

Only line 26 is changed `Some(_) => self.remove(&v)`

This will work:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Val {
    t: HashMap<u16, u16>
}

impl Val {
    fn new() -> Val {
        Val { t: HashMap::new() }
    }

    fn set(&mut self, k: u16, v: u16) {
        self.t.insert(k, v);
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, v: &u16) -> bool {
        match self.t.remove(v) {
            None => false,
            _ => true,
        }
    }

    fn do_work(&mut self, v: u16) -> bool {
        match self.t.get(&v) {
            None => false,
            Some(_) => self.remove(&v)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Val::new();

    v.set(123, 100);
    v.set(1100, 1234);

    println!("Size before: {}", v.t.len());
    println!("Work: {}", v.do_work(123));
    println!("Size after: {}", v.t.len());
}
```

[play.rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e289bb62ed78ce323c8b4fe9e1dfa234)

Comment: No, it's what i want, i want use the result of the get to remove another key, but if you prefer, you can use another case, the goal here if to resolve «mutation in match-arm» design-pattern.

Comment: I changed the example to avoid the confusion.

Comment: This should work https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=27ffdc2e9e46698232943618fec1074a but I can't fully explain the reason :/

Comment: Ok, thank you, i like your solution. I'm waiting for another one. If i have not anyone else, i'll validate yours. Cause i suspect that your solution allocate a new value or do a move of the ownership.

Comment: I have that solution too: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e078a2eb7641b32075037b2d4bca2792
But i'll check if the ownership is not moved

Comment: I'm also interested in better explanation.

Comment: Indeed, your solution makes a copy by using to_owned for types like String (instead of u16). The solution https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e078a2eb7641b32075037b2d4bca2792 seems good for copiable types like u16 (for non-copiable types the ownership is moved).
The code here shows the necessity of cloning: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b62a04441c5fb52d760273036de850a5

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following solution is good for primitive types like here u16. For other types, the ownership is moved.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Val {
    t: HashMap<u16, u16>,
}

impl Val {
    fn new() -> Val {
        Val { t: HashMap::new() }
    }

    fn set(&mut self, k: u16, v: u16) {
        self.t.insert(k, v);
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, v: &u16) -> bool {
        match self.t.remove(v) {
            None => false,
            _ => true,
        }
    }

    fn do_work(&mut self, v: u16) -> bool {
        match self.t.get(&v) {
            None => false,
            Some(&v) => self.remove(&v)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Val::new();

    v.set(123, 100);
    v.set(100, 1234);

    println!("Size before: {}", v.t.len());
    println!("Work: {}", v.do_work(123));
    println!("Size after: {}", v.t.len());
}
```

For other types, we must clone the value:

```rust
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Val {
    t: HashMap<String, String>,
    l: HashSet<String>
}

impl Val {
    fn new() -> Val {
        Val { t: HashMap::new(), l: HashSet::new() }
    }

    fn set(&mut self, k: String, v: String) {
        self.l.insert(v.clone());
        self.t.insert(k, v);
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, v: &String) -> bool {
        self.l.remove(v)
    }

    fn do_work(&mut self, i: &String) -> bool {
        match self.t.get(i) {
            None => false,
            Some(v) => {
                let x = v.clone();

                self.remove(&x)
            }
        }
    }

    fn do_task(&mut self, i: &String) -> bool {
        match self.t.get(i) {
            None => false,
            Some(v) => self.l.insert(v.clone())
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Val::new();

    v.set("AA".to_string(), "BB".to_string());
    v.set("BB".to_string(), "CC".to_string());

    println!("Start: {:#?}", v);
    println!("Size before: {}", v.l.len());
    println!("Work: {}", v.do_work(&"AA".to_string()));
    println!("Size after: {}", v.l.len());
    println!("After: {:#?}", v);
    println!("Task [Exist]: {}", v.do_task(&"BB".to_string()));
    println!("Task [New]: {}", v.do_task(&"AA".to_string()));
    println!("End: {:#?}", v);
}
```

But i'd like a solution that has no allocation